# CSS class selector toggle using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

I am new to web development and trying to create a portfolio website. I am trying to create a full-page nav bar. I am using bootstrap 5 and the navbar works when I click the button on the right, but I want to auto close the navbar when a menu item is selected. I am creating everything in one body with different sections.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container">
            <a onclick="openMenu();" title="" class="btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </a>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="menu_list">
                    <li class="menu_list">
                        <a href="#home" title="" onclick="closeMenu();" class="menu_link">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu_list">
                        <a href="#about-me" title="" onclick="closeMenu();" class="menu_link">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu_list">
                        <a href="#projects" title="" onclick="closeMenu();" class="menu_link">Projects</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu_list">
                        <a href="#contact" title="" onclick="closeMenu();" class="menu_link">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    right: 25px;
    z-index: 3;
    display: flex;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    
}
/*size of the button lines*/
.btn span{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgba(247,72,78,255);
    transition: .5s;
}
/*position of each line within the button space*/
.btn span:nth-child(1){
    top: 25%;
}
.btn span:nth-child(2){
    top: 75%;
}

.btn.is-active span{
    background: rgba(247,72,78,255);
}

/*transformation to X*/
.btn.is-active span:nth-child(1){
    top: 50%;
    transform:  rotate(-45deg);
}
.btn.is-active span:nth-child(2){
    top: 50%;
    transform:  rotate(45deg);
}

/*menu details*/
.menu {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.60);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: .5s;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*when active (clicked)*/
.menu.is-active{
    transition: .5s;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

javascript: open menu() works fine, it's used when the menu is open or closed using btn. The closeMenu() is what I am having difficulty with. I try to make the selection and toggle back to .menu from is-active but it does not work.

```
function openMenu(e){
    let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

    menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
    btn.classList.toggle('is-active');

    e.preventDefault();
}

function closeMenu(){
    let menu = document.querySelector('.menu.is-active');
    let btn = document.querySelector('.btn.is-active');
    menu.classList.toggle('.menu');
    btn.classList.toggle('.btn');
    
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you are using different functions to open and close, why not add the `is-active` in the open, and remove it in the close? It's better than using toggle.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `closeMenu()`, the `menu` and `btn` variables should be selected without the `.is-active` class and then you can toggle the class `.is-active`

```
 function closeMenu(){
        let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
        let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
        menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
        btn.classList.toggle('is-active');
        
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. I was stuck on this for the past 3 hours and can't believe I just had to reuse the same code again. Can you explain the logic behind it, if you don't mind?. because I thought when I clicked it, the current instance was is-active, so to switch back i had to select -.menu-is-select and toggle back to .menu.

Answer (score 0):

you should just remove the . from the 2 last lines.

```
function closeMenu(){
    let menu = document.querySelector('.menu.is-active');
    let btn = document.querySelector('.btn.is-active');
    menu.classList.toggle('menu');
    btn.classList.toggle('btn');
    
    e.preventDefault();
}
```